# admob disappears after changing layout

Tags: android, admob

I am using multiple layouts in my android application.When I change layout by setContentView admob banner disappears.Is there anything I need to do while changing layout.

```
public void setContentView (int layoutResID) 
    {
        super.setContentView(layoutResID);
        // Create the adView
        try {
            // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it's been given
            // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"

        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)
                findViewById(getRespectiveLayoutID(layoutResID));
        //adView.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        // Add the adView to it
        layout.addView(adView);

        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

`i would really appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change the layout, you will need to add the ad to your new layout. An adview is a view, just like a textview, and so what your above code is doing is adding the adview to the layout. When you call `setContentView(R.layout.example)` you change the view, and so you can't see the adview because it is not being shown. To fix this problem, you will have to put the code that you wrote after every setContentView that you call.